# trouble understanding phrase 設定のイメージに近い仕上がり

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble with the following passage in the sentence below.

設定のイメージに近い仕上がり

Google translate gives me "a finish close to the image of the setting".

I've tried looking up 近い仕上がり and it gives me something like "to the point of" or "near ____ quality", but up I'm still unsure of 設定のイメージ. Does it mean something like "visual scenario" or more generally "visual diorama (out of your favourite anime or manga)". Maybe image has a different nuance meaning in Japanese?

Here is the full sentence below

キットのランナーは6色成型。また、フェイスパーツや瞳パーツなどの合計11パーツが塗装済みの仕様で、組み立てただけでも設定のイメージに近い仕上がりをお楽しみいただけます

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42064/7810

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing it, I assume that sentence is referring to a picture on the box of the kit.  They are  indicating that since certain parts are already colored, the final result will look similar to the image just by assembling it, i.e. with no extra effort.  The implication being that you might also paint it if you wanted to get it to look exactly like (rather than 近い, or close to) the image on the box or in the example photo or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

設定のイメージ = Imagined final product/result

You hear this phrase often, especially with assembled products or architecture or a master plan. It envisions what the end result will look like when completed as planned.

> 組み立てただけでも設定のイメージに近い仕上がりをお楽しみいただけます
> Even when only pieced together, you can enjoy having the product look similar to the finished product.